# YouTube "Load More" button

Tags: usability, web-app, lists

YouTube had pagination before "Load More" button era. I could just change the page number in the URL and navigate to a specific page if the channel had many videos. These days if I click the "Go Back" button in browser history and come back to channel, the videos listed are back to default (30). I found it very frustrating.

What do you think about it?

**LE:**

As the [link](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33406/infinite-scroll-vs-pagination-in-e-commerce-websites) suggested, Etsy removed infinite scroll implementation. I consider that the infinite scroll implementation would be a worst approach. You can only use mouse scroll or PU/PD, the scrollbar being useless.

Comment: Check out this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33406/infinite-scroll-vs-pagination-in-e-commerce-websites

Comment: Somewhat different site-type (that one is re: e-commerce), but it still has the same general information.

Comment: This seems to hit several criteria on the [Questions not to ask](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) list (probably all of them at once). It also hits on this from the same page: *"If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."*

Comment: Infinite scroll can work well and is not limited to your

Comment: Infinite scroll can work well on ecommerce websites and is not limited to your "only use mouse scroll or PU/PD, the scrollbar being useless" statement. Check out how it works on [this ecommerce website](http://www.showermania.co.uk/showering/showers) - you can page up/down, use the scroll bar, mouse wheel and when you go back to the page, it will keep you at the same point you were at in the infinite scroll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the current implementation of the YouTube comments very limiting, especially from a UX perspective:

1. It's hard to get to a certain comment
2. I find looking through comments tedious - have to press more every few comments
3. You need to login with Google+

From a business perspective the changes can be justified. Google has always pushed for Google+ users right from the start. It makes sense to integrate into all their product. Plus it also means people won't be able to spam, as their account is associated with their full name (you need your real name to create a g+ account).

On top of that Youtube now sorts by most popular comments by default. I believe most users are happy with that view, and won't do much more.

Comment: I like how you connect your sentences using the word "Plus"